# Moved .py file to another folder, now getting TKinter error only in new folder

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to automate a few analysis processes with Python. At the moment, I have a program that only goes through the directory it is located in, count the number of CSVs and XLSX documents, and prompt the user for a password s/he would like to use to encrypt them. The actual encryption will be done by a library i haven't gotten around to downloading yet, but while making sure that the file worked, I moved it to a another folder and got a new error I am not sure how to parse through.

This is the program:

```
#import pyminizip - lib to download later

import tkinter

from tkinter import messagebox

import os

class whatisthepassword:

    def __init__ (self):

        self.root = tkinter.Tk()

        w = self.root.winfo_screenwidth()

        h = self.root.winfo_screenwidth()

        self.root.geometry("+%d+%d" % ( 200,200) )

        self.root.wm_title("Amir's ZIP & Encrypt shortcut")

        self.frame = tkinter.Frame(self.root)

        self.button_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.root)

        self.pwfield_label = tkinter.Label(self.frame, text = "Password to encrypt files with:", font = 20, width = 25, borderwidth = 2,anchor=tkinter.W)

        self.pwfield = tkinter.Entry(self.frame ,font=20, width = 25, relief = "groove", borderwidth = 2)

        self.begin=tkinter.Button(self.button_frame, text='ZIP & Encrypt', font=20, width=50, command = lambda: self.getpw())

        self.pwfield_label.grid(row=0, column = 0)

        self.pwfield.grid(row = 0, column = 1)  

        self.begin.grid()

        self.frame.pack()

        self.button_frame.pack()

        self.root.mainloop()

    def getpw(self):

        while True:

            pw = (self.pwfield.get())

            if pw == '':

                messagebox.showinfo("Uh oh", "Please enter a password")

                break

            else:

                zipcrypt(pw)

                self.root.destroy()



def zipcrypt(pw):

    folder = os.listdir(os.getcwd())

    numcsvs = 0 # number of csvs

    numxlsx = 0

    for file in folder:

            if '.csv' in file:

                numcsvs += 1

            if '.xlsx' in file:

                numxlsx += 1

    if numcsvs > 1:

        messagebox.showinfo("The Double Do", "You are about to \n\n- ZIP and Encrypt %d .csv file(s) \n- Password Protect %d .xlsx file(s)  \n\nUsing the passphrase \'%s\'\n\nContinue?" % (numcsvs, numxlsx, pw))

def main():

    passwordbox = whatisthepassword()

main()
```

AND this is the error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aj180\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1549, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\aj180\Documents\To Automate\To Automate\create_new_password_zip_folder.py", line 39, in <lambda>
    self.begin=tkinter.Button(self.button_frame, text='ZIP & Encrypt', font=20, width=50, command = lambda: self.getpw())
  File "C:\Users\aj180\Documents\To Automate\To Automate\create_new_password_zip_folder.py", line 57, in getpw
    pw = (self.pwfield.get())
  File "C:\Users\aj180\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2521, in get
    return self.tk.call(self._w, 'get')
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".49912240.49912368"
```

I usually get different decimal values in the last 2 lines.
Does the file change when I move it? What does this error mean?

Also, are there better ways to format my code?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's due to having a `while True` loop around it- you get the contents of `pwfield`, if they're good you go to your `else`, and in your `else` you destroy the root, and by extension all its children. The decimal value is Tcl's identifier for the widget, and since you destroyed the widget, is no longer a viable command.

In all honesty, that loop is entirely irrelevant (avoid while True loops in GUI applications at ALL costs, as they will block the GUI from updating, making it unresponsive) as when the if succeeds it kills the loop and when the if fails it causes a critical error.

Comment: How would you have it check the field is not null without resorting to a while loop?

Comment: @javamirier well, for one you aren't really checking (or rather, when you check, if it's null you `break` out of the loop, thus not looping at all- max loops for this `while True` loop is 1). You could just move the break into your else clause, but that would make it infinite (you can't input into the GUI if the while loop is blocking). The proper way to do it involves the `getpw` function calling itself `after` x milliseconds unless the pw is good. `self.root.after(1000, getpw)` in the null case would do it.